# How to remove quotes in sql-code which is generated by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

How to remove quotes in sql-code which is generated by Entity Framework?
I use .NET 4.0, **Oracle 11**, Ef 5

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{                    
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassName>().ToTable("TableName", "SchemaName");
}
```

Entity Framework generate sql code:

```
SELECT "Extent1"."Field1" AS "Field1"        
FROM "SchemaName"."TableName" "Extent1"
```

I want remove quotes around "SchemaName", because in Oracle I get error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Comment: Are you using the right ADO connector?

Comment: Thank you Grant Winney. The solution is very simple, just to uppercase the user id and the schema name!

Comment: You should use Oracle ADO connector. This is a connectors job to generate SQL. If it's not working, well, you found a bug in the connector. I think there is no way around.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes just enforce case-sensitive naming in Oracle SQL.

All you need here is to use correct case for schema, table and column names and it should work!